# Type 'Any' has no subscript members AND Value of type 'Any' has no member 'Count'

Tags: casting, swift3

I am receiving the following two Errors below when creating an array of Strings in Swift 3.0 on Xcode8:

1. Value of type 'Any' has no member 'count'

   - Original Code: return todoData.count
   - "Fixed" with: return (todoData as AnyObject).count
2. Type 'Any' has no subscript members

   - Original Code: if let text = todoData[indexPath.row] {

See full code below:

```
let todoData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "todosArray")

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let todoData = todoData {
        return todoData.count  //Error 1.
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if let todoData = todoData {
        if let text = todoData[indexPath.row] {  //Error 2.
            cell.label.text = text as? String
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Your issue

is here:

```
let todoData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "todosArray")
```

The compiler has inferred the type of `todoData`to be `Any?`, because that line calls [`UserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults) override of the [`NSObject`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject) method [`value(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1412591-value), which returns `Any?`. You can see for yourself by option-clicking the variable. The type `Any?` doesn't have a property `count`, or a subscript that takes an `Int`.

The naive solution is to just cast it:

```
let todoData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "todosArray") as? [ToDo]
```

But a better option is to replace `value(forKey:)` with a call to [`array(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1414792-array), which will do the cast for you:

```
let todoData = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "todosArray")
```

## As a side note...

this code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let todoData = todoData {
        return todoData.count  //Error 1.
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

can be expressed much more simply as:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return todoData.count ?? 0
}
```

This uses the null coalescing operator (`??`). You can find out more about that, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator#Swift).

And this code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if let todoData = todoData {
        if let text = todoData[indexPath.row] {  //Error 2.
            cell.label.text = text as? String
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

can be rewritten as:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.label.text = todoData?[indexPath.row] as? String
    return cell
}
```

This uses subscripting with optional chaining. You can read more about that, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID250).

Answer (score 0):

Modify your answer to this

```
let todoData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "todosArray")

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let todoData = todoData as? [String] {
        return todoData.count 
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if let todoData = todoData as? [String] {
        if let text = todoData[indexPath.row] {  
            cell.label.text = text
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```